# Calling a sub for different start and end times

Tags: excel, vba

@Variatus Ref the macro you have been working on, for a Friday production the shift will still start at 05:30 but end at 18:30 and if Saturday production the shift will start at 07:00 and finish at 14:00. am I correct in thinking I need to add another Enum called Day 5 Nsh with the start and end time and then same again for day 6 calling it Day 6 Nsh. If this is correct then in the sub Setcompletion how would I call this. would it need to be referenced any where else in the macro also?

```
Enum Nws                ' Worksheet navigation
NwsFirstDataRow = 2
NwsQty = 1          ' Columns (not necessarily contiguous):
NwsTime             ' time to produce one unit
NwsStart            ' date/time
NwsEnd              ' date/time
End Enum
Enum Nsh                ' Shift  (use 24h format)
NshStart = 530      ' read as 05:30 (on current day)
NshEnd = 2430       ' read as 00:30 (on next day)
End Enum
```

next

```
Sub SetCompletion(ws As Worksheet, R As Long)
' 25 Mar 2017

Dim Qty As Long
Dim ShiftQty As Long, DayQty As Long
Dim UnitTime As Double, StartTime As Double
Dim ComplDate As Double
Dim Days As Integer

With Rows(R)
    Qty = .Cells(NwsQty).Value
    UnitTime = .Cells(NwsTime).Value
    StartTime = .Cells(NwsStart).Value
    If Qty And (UnitTime > 0) And (StartTime > 0) Then
        ComplDate = (UnitTime * Qty) + StartTime
        ShiftQty = QtyTillShiftEnd(StartTime, UnitTime)

        If ShiftQty < Qty Then
            Qty = Qty - ShiftQty
            DayQty = DailyProduction(UnitTime)
            ComplDate = Int(StartTime) + 1 + NshToDays(NshStart) + Int(Qty / DayQty)
            ComplDate = ComplDate + UnitTime * (Qty Mod DayQty)
        End If

        .Cells(NwsEnd).Value = ComplDate
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

next

```
Private Function QtyTillShiftEnd(ByVal StartTime As Double, _
                              ByVal UnitTime As Double) As Double
' 20 Mar 2017

Dim ProdTime As Double

ProdTime = (Int(StartTime) + NshToDays(NshEnd) - StartTime)
QtyTillShiftEnd = (ProdTime + 0.0001) / UnitTime
End Function
```

next

```
Private Function DailyProduction(UnitTime As Double) As Integer
' 19 Mar 2017
DailyProduction = Int((NshToDays(NshEnd) - NshToDays(NshStart) + 0.000001) / UnitTime)
End Function
```

next

```
Private Function NshToDays(TimeCode As Nsh) As Double
' 19 Mar 2017

Dim H As Double, M As Double

H = Int(TimeCode / 100)
M = TimeCode Mod 100
NshToDays = (1 / 24 * H) + (1 / 24 / 60 * M)
End Function
```

next

```
Function AdjustedStartTime(ByVal StartTime As Double) As Double
' 19 Mar 2017
' return new StartTime or 0

Dim Fun As Double
Dim StartDate As Long
Dim ShiftStart As Double, ShiftEnd As Double

ShiftStart = NshToDays(NshStart)
ShiftEnd = NshToDays(NshEnd)
StartDate = Int(StartTime)
StartTime = StartTime - StartDate
Fun = StartTime

If ShiftEnd > 1 Then
    If StartTime < (ShiftStart - Int(ShiftStart)) Then
        If StartTime > (ShiftEnd - Int(ShiftEnd)) Then Fun = ShiftStart
    End If
Else
    If (StartTime - Int(StartTime)) < ShiftStart Then
        Fun = ShiftStart
    Else
        If StartTime > ShiftEnd Then Fun = ShiftStart + 1
    End If
End If
AdjustedStartTime = Fun + StartDate
End Function
```

Comment: In order to make this question compatible with site rules please publish the code for Enum Nsh, Sub SetCompletion, and Functions QtyTillShiftEnd, DailyProduction, NashToDays and AdjustedStartTime. You risk having it thrown out otherwise, and you might get some very intelligent input if you comply. Yes, the different times need to be added to the enum, but it will probably take another function to determine if there is a Saturday between start and finish. Once Saturday is done, will you disclose that Sunday is off? Now is the better time to say so.

Comment: Hi, added code to qusetion as advised. Saurday production will not always be worked so would a check box or similar overcome this ie. if box is checked Saturday production will be included in calculation if not checked then Saturday and Sunday are skipped (Sunday will never be worked)

Answer (score 0):

Plese set up a named range in your workbook and call it "SpecialDays". I suggest you create a dedicated worksheet to house it and make it accessible throughout the workbook. The picture below illustrates and explains.
[image: Named Range "SpecialDays"]

The program's logic will be like this:-

- There will be no production on any day marked as Holiday
- There will be a short shift on any day marked as "Half shift"
- There will be a full shift on any day marked as "full shift"
- There will be no work on weekends unless the days are marked as Special Days
- There will be a full shift on all other days

The important part of this list is in the sequence: whichever condition applies first is the condition that prevails. For example, there will be a full shift on Sunday Dec 31 because the condition for "full shift" is met before that of the day being a Sunday, but if it were also listed as a holiday (in a second row, anywhere in the list) there would be no work because holidays are filtered out first.

In order to connect the range to your code, please add these three lines above the enums on your code sheet.

```
' a named range of this name must exist:
' it must have 2 columns, first with a date, 2nd with a number as Nsh
Const SpecialDays As String = "SpecialDays"
```

You can change the name of the range here, but must make sure that you use the same name here and on the worksheet where you name the range.

Now, as you already suggested, the Enum Nsh needs to be extended. Here it is. Just replace the existing with the new, in its entirety (meaning form the declaration to "End Enum".

```
Enum Nsh                ' Shift
    ' 28 Mar 2017
    NshFullShift = 0
    NshHalfShift
    NshNoShift
    NshStart = 530      ' read as 05:30 (on current day)
    NshEnd = 2430       ' read as 00:30 (on next day)
    NshHalfStart = 700  ' (use 24h format)
    NshHalfEnd = 1400
End Enum
```

The first three enumeration correspond to the numbers you may enter in the "SpecialDays" range's 2nd column.

Of course, the SetCompletion procedure must be modified. It now calculates each day's production individually instead of presuming that every day's output is the same.

```
Sub SetCompletion(Ws As Worksheet, R As Long)
    ' 28 Mar 2017

    Dim Qty As Long, ShiftQty As Long
    Dim CommenceTime As Double, UnitTime As Double
    Dim ComplTime As Double

    With Rows(R)
        Qty = .Cells(NwsQty).Value
        UnitTime = .Cells(NwsTime).Value
        CommenceTime = .Cells(NwsStart).Value
        If Qty And (UnitTime > 0) And (CommenceTime > 0) Then
            ComplTime = CommenceTime + (UnitTime * Qty)
            Qty = Qty - QtyTillShiftEnd(CommenceTime, UnitTime)

            If Qty > 0 Then
                Do While Qty > 0
                    ComplTime = Int(ComplTime) + 1
                    ShiftQty = DailyProduction(ComplTime, UnitTime)
                    If Qty > ShiftQty Then
                        Qty = Qty - ShiftQty
                    Else
                        ComplTime = ComplTime + StartTime(ShiftType(ComplTime)) + (Qty * UnitTime)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If

            .Cells(NwsEnd).Value = ComplTime
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The daily production is different on different days. The new function therefore receives the date as an argument and calculates the production according to what kind of day it is: Holiday, half-shift or full-shift day. Of course, the same holds true for the calculation on the first day of production which starts at the CommenceTime, not the start of the shift.

```
Private Function QtyTillShiftEnd(ByVal CommenceTime As Double, _
                                 ByVal UnitTime As Double) As Double
    ' 28 Mar 2017

    Dim ProdTime As Double
    Dim ShType As Nsh

    ShType = ShiftType(CommenceTime)
    ProdTime = Int(CommenceTime) + EndTime(ShType) - CommenceTime
    QtyTillShiftEnd = Int((ProdTime + 0.0001) / UnitTime)
End Function

Private Function DailyProduction(ShiftDay As Double, _
                                 UnitTime As Double) As Integer
    ' 28 Mar 2017

    Dim ShType As Nsh

    ShType = ShiftType(ShiftDay)
    DailyProduction = Int((EndTime(ShType) - StartTime(ShType) + 0.0001) / UnitTime)
End Function
```

The NshToDays function remains unchanged in principle, but I modified the method by which the parameter is received (ByVal instead of the previous default ByRef).

```
Private Function NshToDays(ByVal TimeCode As Nsh) As Double
    ' 28 Mar 2017

    Dim H As Double, M As Double

    H = Int(TimeCode / 100)
    M = TimeCode Mod 100
    NshToDays = (1 / 24 * H) + (1 / 24 / 60 * M)
End Function
```

The next function has undergone a complete overhaul. It will now find the start of the next shift even if the entered start time is several days from where it should be.

```
Function AdjustedStartTime(ByVal CommenceTime As Double) As Double
    ' 28 Mar 2017
    ' return new CommenceTime or 0

    Dim StartDate As Long
    Dim ShType As Nsh

    StartDate = Int(CommenceTime)
    ' if StartDate isn't a workday, then loop for a workday
    Do
        ShType = ShiftType(StartDate)
        If ShType <> NshNoShift Then Exit Do
        StartDate = StartDate + 1
    Loop

    If StartDate < CommenceTime Then
        ' StartDate is a workday:
        If CommenceTime > (StartDate + EndTime(ShType)) Then
            StartDate = StartDate + 1
        End If
    End If

    If StartDate < CommenceTime Then
        CommenceTime = CommenceTime - StartDate
        CommenceTime = Application.Max(CommenceTime, StartTime(ShType))
    Else
        CommenceTime = StartTime(ShType)
    End If

    AdjustedStartTime = CommenceTime + StartDate
End Function
```

The FormatCells procedure is the sole survivor from March 25. I believe you have taken complete charge of it and know how to modify it to do what you want if it doesn't do so on its own.

There are three more new procedures which you can paste at the bottom of your code sheet (not the one with the even procedure). ShiftType is the function which refers to the SpecialDays and determines which, if any, are the start and end times for the daily shift.

```
Private Function ShiftType(ByVal ShiftDate As Double) As Nsh
    ' 28 Mar 2017

    Dim Fun As Nsh
    Dim Rng As Range, Fnd As Range
    Dim Fmt As String

    ShiftDate = Int(ShiftDate)
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(SpecialDays).RefersToRange.Columns(1)

    With Rng
        Fmt = .Cells(1).NumberFormat
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        Set Fnd = .Find(What:=ShiftDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        .NumberFormat = Fmt
    End With

    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        Fun = Application.Weekday(ShiftDate)
        If (Fun = vbSaturday) Or (Fun = vbSunday) Then
            Fun = NshNoShift
        Else
            Fun = NshFullShift
        End If
    Else
        Fun = CLng(Val(Fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value))
        Fun = Application.Min(Fun, NshNoShift)
        Fun = Application.Max(Fun, NshFullShift)
    End If
    ShiftType = Fun
End Function
```

The last two functions return the StartTime and EndTime depending upon the ShiftType. Note that they return 0 (zero) for off-days.

```
Private Function StartTime(ShType As Nsh) As Double
    ' 28 Mar 2017
    On Error Resume Next
    StartTime = NshToDays(Array(NshStart, NshHalfStart, 0)(ShType))
    Err.Clear
End Function

Private Function EndTime(ShType As Nsh) As Double
    ' 28 Mar 2017
    On Error Resume Next
    EndTime = NshToDays(Array(NshEnd, NshHalfEnd, 0)(ShType))
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

Basically, your code works as before but it has become a lot more complex, meaning it has a lot more points where something may have gone without sufficient attention. My hope is that you will be able to find the procedure responsible for any fault you might discover and either can fix it yourself. After all, each procedure is rather simple in itself. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much again. I will update and test over the next few days.

Comment: Hi I have set up the SpecialDays sheet and named as this. It is giving the error message "Compile error: Variable not defined" and highlighting (SpecialDays) in the private function shift type. `Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(SpecialDays).RefersToRange.Columns(1)`. I have researched the error message and found that you have to declare variables. Is this not done in this piece of code `Dim Rng As Range, Fnd As Range`

Comment: That was an omission I made and I apologise. Please read in my answer above, below the picture of the named range. I have added the missing information there. Add those 3 lines of code & remarks to your existing code.